# Not able to POST image files to server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http

I'm trying to send an image to server using `POST` request but on server side I'm receiving and empty object.

```js
  // Client Side

  function uploadFile(thumbnailRef) {
    const thumbnail = thumbnailRef.current.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', thumbnail)

   fetch('http://localhost:8080/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },

    }).then(res => { console.log(res) })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

  }
```

```js
  // server side

  app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // getting empty - {}
    res.end()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you remove headers. Like this:

```
function uploadFile(thumbnailRef) {
    const thumbnail = thumbnailRef.current.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', thumbnail)

   fetch('http://localhost:8080/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,

    }).then(res => { console.log(res) })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

  }
```